# Java parsing string input

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I'm having problem parsing a particular input case.  I'm using scanning class to deal with this. I tried using trim function but didn't seem to work. I guess one way to go about this is to use a Regular expression but how would I do that in this case? Any other solutions?
The input I am having a problem with is :

```
55, 34, 12, 1
```

or

```
55, 34,      12, 1
```

Its when I put an input of spaces and not continuous commas.

This input will work:

```
55,34,12,1
```

My Code:

```
public class Excercise3


{

    public static double round(double value, int places) 
    {
        if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
       String test = scan.nextLine();   
     // String test = scan.next();      
        //test.trim();
        String delims = "[,]";        
        String[] strarray = test.split(delims);


        for (String str : strarray)
        {

            Integer numofWidgets = Integer.parseInt(str);

                if (numofWidgets > 0 && numofWidgets <= 12)
                {                               
                    System.out.print("The widgets will cost " + (round(((numofWidgets * 12.39) + 3), 2) + "\n"));
                }
                else if ( numofWidgets > 12 && numofWidgets <= 50 )
                {
                    if (numofWidgets > 30 )
                    {                       
                        System.out.print("The widgets will cost " + (round(((numofWidgets * 11.99) + 5), 2) + "\n"));
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        System.out.print("The widgets will cost " + (round(((numofWidgets * 11.99) + 3), 2) + "\n"));
                    }
                }
                else if (  numofWidgets > 50)
                {

                    System.out.print("The widgets will cost " + (round(((numofWidgets * 11.49) + 5), 2) + "\n"));
                }


        }               
        scan.close(); 

    }



}
```

Important fix:

```
String test = scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

just split them by

```
String delims = ",";
```

and before parsing into it use `trim()`

```
Integer numofWidgets = Integer.parseInt(str.trim());
```

Comment: I have to change this line String test = scan.nextLine(); It works now!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try replacing all the space in the string with

```
test = test.replace(" ","");
```

before splitting with `split()` method

This should transform your input in this way

```
55, 34,      12, 1 ---> 55,34,12,1
```

Comment: I had to change this line String test = scan.nextLine(); it works now!